# We have Flutter App on Google Play Store, we want to increase the app size on play store, how can we do that?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-play

We have an existing Flutter App on Google Play Store and the customer wants to increase the app size on Google Play Store, how can we do that ?

We tried to upload appbundles but we couldn't find a proper explanation for Flutter

Comment: You want to **in**crease the app's size? What for? Or did you mean **de**crease?

Comment: So the customer wants to add new videos or pics into the app, and for that we want to increase the data limit of the app

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How big is your app at the moment? You can upload multiple bundle (multidex config in gradle build file has to be enabled) to make sure also a big size app is available. There are apps or games having a size 1GB+.